# SONAR SCANNER not running - unable to connect to sonarqube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm able to access sonarqube server from my build agent browser - it loads fine.
Im able to telnet to my sonarqube server from the same build agent and telnet works fine. I'm able to hit a CURL to my sonarqube api (api/authentication/validate) and i get a valid=true response.

When in invoke my sonar-scanner i get SONARQUBE SERVER CANNOT BE REACHED ERROR.
I have given "Anyone" user execute analysis permission in my SONAR server. I have only my sonar server url given in sonar scanner. I copied my sonar scanner and the same project to another build VM and im able to build fine.

not sure what im missing here, please help

Answer (score 1):

Your error is "server cannot be reached", so this doesn't have anything to do with permissions to execute an analysis.

At a guess, your global scanner configuration doesn't point correctly to your SonarQube instance. You can override that at the analysis level using `-Dsonar.host.url=[your URL here]` or you can find and fix the global config. I'd tell you what to look for, but you don't say which scanner you're using.

Comment: Hi Ann, im using SOANR-SCANNER version SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141, Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit), Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64. I also tried passing -Dsonar.host.url=[your URL here] while invoking sonar scanner, but still same issue. The URL is also correct

Comment: Upon further analysis we found its bcz of socket timeout and there is some slight latency in connecting the sonar server from the build agent, is it recommended to change the socket setting @ the server side, please share your thoughts